# Расшифровать данные PKCS #7, зашифрованные по ГОСТ 28147

Tags: c#, шифрование, гост

Есть файл в формате PKCS #7 с данными, зашифрованными по алгоритму ГОСТ 28147. Сертификат и закрытый ключ экспортированы в файл `pfx`. Пытаюсь расшифровать данные, используя библиотеку BouncyCastle 1.8.1:

```
var cmsEnvelopedData = new CmsEnvelopedData(File.ReadAllBytes(@"encrypted-file.bin"));
var recipient1 = cmsEnvelopedData.GetRecipientInfos().GetRecipients().Cast<RecipientInformation>().First();

string path = @"cert.pfx";
string password = "1111";
var builder = new Pkcs12StoreBuilder();
var store = builder.Build();
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    store.Load(stream, password.ToCharArray());
}
var privateKey = store.GetKey(store.Aliases.Cast<string>().Single()).Key;

byte[] data1 = recipient1.GetContent(privateKey);
```

На последней строчке валится ошибка:

> Org.BouncyCastle.Cms.CmsException: couldn't create cipher. --->
>   Org.BouncyCastle.Security.SecurityUtilityException: Cipher
>   1.2.643.2.2.19 not recognised.
>       at Org.BouncyCastle.Security.CipherUtilities.GetCipher(String algorithm) 
>   at
>   Org.BouncyCastle.Security.WrapperUtilities.GetWrapper(String algorithm)
>   at
>   Org.BouncyCastle.Cms.KeyTransRecipientInformation.UnwrapKey(ICipherParameters key)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>       at Org.BouncyCastle.Cms.KeyTransRecipientInformation.UnwrapKey(ICipherParameters key)
>   at
>   Org.BouncyCastle.Cms.KeyTransRecipientInformation.GetContentStream(ICipherParameters key)
>   at
>   Org.BouncyCastle.Cms.RecipientInformation.GetContent(ICipherParameters key)

Похоже, метод GetContent не может распарсить закрытый ключ. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: 1.2.643.2.2.19 - расширение (или как они назывались) от GOST R 34.10-2001, наверно где от отдельно надо указывать, чтобы работало.

Comment: Если ничего не путаю, то где то должен использоваться `Gost28147Engine`, но где именно - без понятия. Если что, он реализует интерфейс `IBlockCipher`.

Comment: Порылся в исходниках - у вашего `recipient1` в свойствах можно явно глянуть, какой алгоритм считается подходящим. И да, `1.2.643.2.2.19` похоже просто не поддерживается библиотекой, но тут я не уверен.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [этой](https://cpdn.cryptopro.ru/content/csp40/html/group___pro_c_s_p_ex_DP8.html) табличке, алгоритм шифрования всего один, и он действительно 28147, только OID у него 1.2.643.2.2.21.

У вас же, судя по ошибке, OID  1.2.643.2.2.19, который относится к экспорту/импорту ключей. Так что, либо вы взяли не тот файл, либо неправильно подошли к расшифровке.

На тему расшифровки, я бы советовал посмотреть в сторону например [этого вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5910454/3768545), хотя может я и ошибаюсь.

Comment: Да, ошибка относится именно к ключам. Но файл PFX 100% рабочий, я через BC именно этим файлом могу успешно подписывать данные (через CmsSignedDataGenerator) и верифицировать подпись. С этими ключами не хочет работать именно класс RecipientInformation (относящийся к CmsEnvelopedData). Возможно, я как-то не так его использую. Поэтому вопрос мой можно переформулировать так: как имея ключ в формате PFX и файл PKCS #7 расшифровать лежащие в этом файле данные?

Comment: По вашей ссылке нет примеров работы ни с PFX, ни с PKCS #7, так что в решении вопроса она мало может помочь

Comment: @AndreBorges если у вас найдутся тестовые данные - всмысле пара открытый-закрытый ключ, то может попробую как нибудь провести цикл шифрования-расшифровки. Прямо так по памяти ничего не скажу, надо гуглить и пробовать.